# Stop Thunderbird auto start after login in Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, thunderbird, autostart

I am looking for a way to stop my Thunderbird application auto start.

However I don't want to just remove the application, because may I need it in the future, and some important letters are only stored in there.

I tried to check the 'Startup Applications', but I didn't see the Thunderbird client.

How can I stop Thunderbird from starting automatically each time?

--Edit: --

Inside the

> /home/user/.config/autostart

Folder I didn't find a thunderbird.desktop entry either.
[image]

Based on the commenteries, I also tried to check the ~/.config/upstart/ folder, and the .profile file. Unfortunately I didn't find the solution.

Every answer will be appreciated!

Comment: Check if there is a .desktop entry for thunderbird in '/home/user/.config/autostart' and delete it, where 'user' is your username.

Comment: I've just checked, but there is no thunderbird.desktop inside the .config/autostart/ folder.

Comment: what files are in this folder, one of them should be responsible for the autostart of thunderbird

Comment: I've just edited the post above. Seriously I have no idea, I just check each of them.

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu there are basicly three places in which you can set programs to start on login:

- a *.desktop file in `~/.config/autostart/` in which you define the command you want to run, these files can be set active or inactive via `Startup Applications`
- any commands put inside `.profile`
- as third place there is `~/.config/upstart/` which is an leftover of upstart, the init-replacement, now dropped for systemd

If nowhere there you can find an entry for thunderbird, things might have got quite funny.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I've just checked all the file locations what you wrote. There is no command related to the Thunderbird in the .profile file, and the ~/.config/upstart/ folder is empty. 
I didn't make any modification for the Thunderbird, I believe it is installed by default.